# Create getter/setter does not show anymore

Tags: intellij-idea

I somehow manages to change my settings such that I do not get the suggestion for generating getter/setter methods. At least not for all types.

The image below shows that `name`, in contrast to the fields `id` and `appUser`, is not greyed out:

[image]

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get a suggestion for "*Create getter and setter*" for `id`

[image]

But this does not happen for the field `name`:

[image]

I remember pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> accidentally and since then my settings seems to be messed up. Since I couldn't find anything in *Settings* I was hoping somebody could help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to generate Getter/Setter was suggested by *Unused Declaration* inspection (*Java | Declaration redundancy | Unused declaration*).

Also the fix to suppress the inspection is suggested in case it's annotated by particular annotation:
[image]

Probably you've mistakenly applied the suppression, so the `@Column` annotation was added to "Entry points" list. 
To remove the annotation from this list do the following:
- open the inspection's settings -> **Entry points** pane:
[image]

- press the "Annotations..."
- and remove the `@Column` annotation from the list
- save